# Any Python library that reads and resize the Sentinel 2 image with 10 bands

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio

I found a Python library "imread" in github that reads raster image with more than 3 band. But it only does that I was wondering is there other library that resize the image like how we can resize RGB with 3 band. I know GDAL does that but I am not good with GDAL in Python. How can I do this from GDAL or rasterio?

Example with opencv2

```
list=[]
r = cv2.imread("path")
r = cv2.resize(r,(shape to resize))
r.append(list)
```

Comment: Your question does not show appropriate research effort. The rasterio documentation has many examples: https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resampling.html#resampling

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rasterio`.
This is the documentation:
https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resampling.html

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.enums import Resampling

with rasterio.open("example.tif") as dataset:

    # resample data to target shape
    data = dataset.read(
        out_shape=(
            dataset.count,
            new_height,
            new_width
        ),
        resampling=Resampling.bilinear #you can also use nearest or bicubic if you want
    )

    # scale image transform
    transform = dataset.transform * dataset.transform.scale(
        (dataset.width / data.shape[-1]),
        (dataset.height / data.shape[-2])
    )
```